# Use stash notifier plugin on Jenkins 2.0 multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server, jenkins-2

I don't know how to setup the stash notifier plugin on a multibranch pipeline.
The configuration page does not have a 'Post-build Actions section'.

Answer (score 8):

Stash Notifier now supports Pipelines as of version 1.11.

From the [examples in the README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/stashnotifier-plugin#note-on-pipeline-plugin-usage):

```
node {
    step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])         // Notifies the Stash Instance of an INPROGRESS build

    try {
        // Do stuff
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'     // Set result of currentBuild !Important!
    } catch(err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'      // Set result of currentBuild !Important!
    }

    step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])         // Notifies the Stash Instance of the build result
}
```

While it says that setting currentBuild.result is "!Important!", my experience has been that this is only the case if your steps aren't already doing that. For example, if you have `sh "false"`, you don't need to wrap that in a try/catch because the `sh` step will set the build result to failed on a non-zero exit code. This should only be necessary if you need custom success/failure logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is still not compatible with the pipeline or multibranch pipeline job type.

I think Abhijeet Kamble means that you can just use a http client or curl to send the updates yourself.

Something like this:

```
withCredentials([[$class          : 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: "$env.componentCredentialsId",
          usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
   writeFile file: 'build.json', text: "{\"state\": \"SUCCESSFUL\", \"key\": \"${env.JOB_NAME}\", \"name\": \"${env.BUILD_TAG}\", \"url\": \"${env.BUILD_URL}\"}"
   sh '''curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST $URL -d @build.json'''
}
```

Do note that it is a very simple example, not as sophisticated as the plugin.

Comment: couldn't get plugin to work because credentialsID didn't work w/ the latest Jenkins 2.x...they don't use a UUID any more.  This was the simplest thing to do...

Comment: Also note that the URL has to be in the format: https://<stash-base-url>/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/<commit-hash>

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stash Notifier by adding it as a Post Step in your Jenkins build job configuration.

In your Jenkins job configuration go to the Post-build Actions section, click on Add post-build action and select Notify Stash Instance
Enter the Stash base URL, `e. g. http://localhost:7990 or http://my.company/stash.`

If in doubt, go to your local Stash server and check the URL in the browser. The URL `http://georg@localhost:7991/projects` e. g. reveals the server base URL, which is `http://localhost:7991` in this case.
Use the Credentials Plugin to select credentials for stash.

Comment: As I put in my question: "The configuration page does not have a 'Post-build Actions section'." Does your Jenkins 2 multibranch pipeline have such a section?

Comment: this only works if you use a standard jenkins job...the question was how to do it w/ pipeline and I think you have to be able to call the plugin as a step.